# Custom pipe with async not showing

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm trying to use the id to get user data. The pipe takes in the id and uses a service which requests a users data based on the id and returns a Observable user data.

Here is the pipe:

```
export class UserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  transform(value: number): Observable<User> {


      return this.userService.getFriendBy(value)
 }

}
```

I have tried to use the pipe as follow:

```
<h2 float-left>{{  (chat.user_to_chat_id | user)?.first_name | async }}</h2>
```

Comment: get the property after the async pipe 
`<h2 float-left>{{  (chat.user_to_chat_id | user | async)?.first_name }}</h2>`

Comment: Thank you! Although it is `first_name` if you refer to OP :)